# How to iterate and consolidate javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a JavaScript object that looks something like this. It's basically something that I get as an output from a certain API. The object is structured such that it may contain multiple instances of same 'equity' (see Hitachi Home below):

```
  {
    "results": {
      "holdings": [{
        "equity": {
          "text": "Hitachi Home"
        },
        "holding_pc": "6.48",
        "sector": "Consumer Durables",
        "shares_no": "1537.00",
        "value_cr": "0.24"
      }, {
        "equity": {
          "text": "Mahindra CIE"
        },
        "holding_pc": "6.34",
        "sector": "Manufacturing",
        "shares_no": "10376.00",
        "value_cr": "0.24"
      }, {
        "equity": {
          "text": "Schneider Infra"
        },
        "holding_pc": "5.33",
        "sector": "Utilities",
        "shares_no": "9518.00",
        "value_cr": "0.20",
      }, {
        "equity": {
          "text": "Hitachi Home"
        },
        "holding_pc": "2.18",
        "sector": "Consumer Durables",
        "shares_no": "437.00",
        "value_cr": "0.12"
      }]
    }
  }
```

What's the best way to write a JavaScript function that takes this whole object as an input, iterates over all records and consolidates it such that records with same 'equity' are summed and consolidated. For instance in the output the equity 'Hitachi Home' should look something like this:

```
  {
    "results": {
      "holdings": [{
        "equity": {
          "text": "Hitachi Home"
        },
        "holding_pc": "8.66",
        "sector": "Consumer Durables",
        "shares_no": "1974.00",
        "value_cr": "0.36"
      }, {
        "equity": {
          "text": "Mahindra CIE"
        },
        "holding_pc": "6.34",
        "sector": "Manufacturing",
        "shares_no": "10376.00",
        "value_cr": "0.24"
      }, {
        "equity": {
          "text": "Schneider Infra"
        },
        "holding_pc": "5.33",
        "sector": "Utilities",
        "shares_no": "9518.00",
        "value_cr": "0.20",
      }]
    }
  }
```

Basically, I am trying to write a JS function which will sum up all equities with same text. Here's what am broadly heading towards:

```
function transform(data) {
  function sumHoldings(row) {
    newrow = {};
    newrow.equity = row.equity.text;
    newrow.holding_pc = row.holding_pc;
    return newrow;
  }
  for(var holdings in data.results) {
    data.results.total_holdings = data.results.holdings.map(sumHoldings);
  };

  return data;
}
```

Comment: so, show what you try

Comment: @Grundy just added my current code. I'll also try to put a fiddle.

Comment: why you use this `for(var holdings in data.results) {`? `results` is object with one property `holdings`. Seems like you not need this loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the original array as follows:

```js
var obj = {
  "results": {
    "holdings": [{
      "equity": {
        "text": "Hitachi Home"
      },
      "holding_pc": "6.48",
      "sector": "Consumer Durables",
      "shares_no": "1537.00",
      "value_cr": "0.24"
    }, {
      "equity": {
        "text": "Mahindra CIE"
      },
      "holding_pc": "6.34",
      "sector": "Manufacturing",
      "shares_no": "10376.00",
      "value_cr": "0.24"
    }, {
      "equity": {
        "text": "Schneider Infra"
      },
      "holding_pc": "5.33",
      "sector": "Utilities",
      "shares_no": "9518.00",
      "value_cr": "0.20",
    }, {
      "equity": {
        "text": "Hitachi Home"
      },
      "holding_pc": "2.18",
      "sector": "Consumer Durables",
      "shares_no": "437.00",
      "value_cr": "0.12"
    }]
  }
}

function findFirst(items, predicate) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (predicate(items[i])) {
      return items[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}

var result = obj.results.holdings.reduce(function (arr, it) {
  it.holding_pc = Number(it.holding_pc);
  it.shares_no = Number(it.shares_no);
  it.value_cr = Number(it.value_cr);
  var holding = findFirst(arr, function (_it) { return _it.equity.text === it.equity.text });
  if (holding) {
    // If item is found make calculations
    holding.holding_pc += it.holding_pc;
    holding.shares_no += it.shares_no;
    holding.value_cr += it.value_cr;
  } else {
    // If item is not found aded to the array
    arr.push(it);
  }
  return arr;
}, []);


document.querySelector('#out').innerHTML = JSON.stringify({ results: { holdings: result } }, undefined, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest making an object for holdings that would consolidate the data and could be accessed by holdings names (which I asssume are unique here).

This way you iterate over your holdings array and assign the data from the original object to a new one, generally like this:

```
    var consolidatedHoldings = {};

    obj.results.holdings.forEach(function(holding){
        holding.forEach(function (holdingDataValue, holdingDataIndex) {
            // checking if the value is a number
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat(holdingDataValue)) && isFinite(holdingDataValue)) {
                consolidatedHoldings[holdingDataIndex] = consolidatedHoldings[holdingDataIndex] + parseFloat(holdingDataValue);
            } else {
                consolidatedHoldings[holdingDataValue] = holdingDataValue;
            }
        });
    });
```

This way if the key didn't exist, it gets created. If it did its overwritten (expectedly with the same value). Plus if this is a number it gets added.

You end up with a consolidated holdings object, which then you may want to turn into an array and put into your original object.

Comment: It says 'holding.forEach' is not a function

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = {};

a.holdings.forEach(function(holding){  
   var text = holding.equity.text;
   var entry = map[text] || (map[text] = []);

   entry.push(holding);
});

Object.keys(map).map(function(key) {
  var values = map[key];
  var parseFloats = function(a, b) { return parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b); };

  return {
     equity: {
        "text" : key
     },
     sector : values[0].sector,
     value_cr: values.map(function(e) { return e.value_cr; }).reduce(parseFloats, 0), 
     shares_no: values.map(function(e) { return e.shares_no; }).reduce(parseFloats, 0), 
     holding_pc : values.map(function(e) { return e.holding_pc; }).reduce(parseFloats, 0)
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate the arrays, not the objects. Unless you are interested in iterating the properties of the object. Something like:

```
obj.results.holdings.forEach(function(holding){
    //holding.equity.text holds the equity string.
    //It's up to you how to deal with the uniqueness.
    //You could just push it into an array if the equity.text value isn't within the array.
});
```

Edit: I figured out you wanted to reduce the array, not find unique.

```
var equity = { };
var sums = ['holding_pc', 'shares_no', 'value_cr'];
var holdings = obj.results.holdings.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue){
    var currentEquity = currentValue.equity.text;
    if(equity[currentEquity] !== undefined){
        //Equity exists in reduced array
        oldObj = previousValue[equity[currentEquity]];
        sums.forEach(function(prop){
           oldObj[prop] = Number(oldObj[prop]) + Number(currentValue[prop]); 
        });
    } else {
      //Equity doesn't exist
        equity[currentEquity] = previousValue.length;
        previousValue.push(currentValue);
    }
    return previousValue;
}, []);
//holdings is now a reduced array (not the result object, result.holdings array).
```

Comment: Am not sure if I get this. Pls refer my code. I am trying to put this in a separate object 'total_holdings' as you suggested.

Comment: Basically, the information you are interested to iterate is in the results.holdings array. In my code, holding is the current item being iterated. Each item is an object which contains a property called equity which is an object that holds a property called text. It's up to you to do whatever you want with this property .I figured out that you wanted to just take non-repeated values, but it might not be what you want to do.